# Does CSS use pixel ratios or some fraction of an inch?

Tags: css, user-interface, pixel

I've read two things about the size of the CSS pixel:

1) 1px = 0.75pt, where 1pt = 1/72 inch

2) 1px = (physical pixel size) * (pixel ratio)

So in (1), the width of 1px is 0.75/72 inches, whereas in (2), if the pixel ratio is 2, the width of 1px is 2x the width of a physical pixel.

Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The MDN gives a short summary of the pixel in CSS. A single pixel in CSS is based on a pixel density of 96 DPI.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_pixel

I discovered a Github document published by Vincent Hardy and Sylvain Galineau about the subject of CSS pixel and device pixel ratios.

https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/

Review the above link for details. The short version is that CSS pixels are displayed based on 1/96 of a physical inch. So it appears the answer is CSS pixel divided by device pixel ratio. It is a 1-to-1 mapping if the device pixel resolution is 96dpi.

> Example given in the article: On a MacBook Pro 15-inch display with a resolution of 110dpi, the physical width of a box is: 96 * 1 / 110 = 0.872 inch. This is because the CSS pixel to device pixel ratio is 1. Using a ruler on my screen I measured 0.88 inch and the difference is a rudimentary ruler and approximate vision. So a CSS inch is off by 22.8% from the physical inch.

Comment: Thank you, yep. I'm just wondering whether it's (1) or (2) ^^ that they use to generate that pixel size to satisfy the 96DPI thing.

Comment: @RNdev I found a Github document published by Vincent Hardy and Sylvain Galineau about this very subject! I will also edit my answer to include this:  https://webplatform.github.io/docs/tutorials/understanding-css-units/ -- Go down to the heading entitled "On CSS pixels, physical units and scalability"
 -- It discusses how the CSS pixel interacts with DPPI (device pixels per inch). 1/96 of a physical inch is a pixel. So when CSS renders, it is CSS pixel divided by device pixel ratio.